# If there is possibility to use two or more activities in gdx?

Tags: android, libgdx

I wanted to open another activity or show native android dialog from AndroidLauncher in gdx. But when I add MyActivity and MyDialog classes, there is an error "Error: The number of method references cannot exceed 64K". But when I delete this classes everything works fine. Is there a way to open another activity in LibGDX game?

Comment: If you want to show native dialogs you should look into the "native-dialogs" extention for Gdx.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use add a `Multidex` support to exceed the 65k methods limit. Here's a guide to integrate `Google Play` with `GDX`. Search in there for the 'DEX' part and apply it to your project.

https://chandruscm.wordpress.com/2015/12/30/how-to-setup-google-play-game-services-in-libgdx-using-android-studio/

You'll be fine!